# PHP function within a function with namespaces

Tags: php

I can't really seem to call my function within a function with namespaces. I know that

```
\foo\bar::foo_bar();
```

Will call this function

```
function foo_bar() {
    return('This is foo_bar');
}
```

But what if I have a function like so

```
static function foo_bar() {
    function foo() {
        return('This is foo');
    }
}
```

I have many other functions within `foo_bar` like

```
static function foo_bar() {
    function foo() {
        return('This is foo');
    }
    function bar() {
        return('This is bar');
    }
}
```

So I was thinking `\foo();` but it just says `Fatal error: Call to undefined function foo() in`. Then if I do something like `\foo\bar\foo_bar::foo();`, it'll give me this error `Fatal error: Class '\foo\bar\foo_bar' not found in`.

How would I go about to call my function within a function?

Comment: The function in a function gets only defined when the function where it is defined in gets called once. But then the function inside it  is normally  callable like the function it's defined in. P.S. Don't define a function in a function. It's bad practice.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Technically, it's not bad practice. What if you had a function like `function foo($str) { return($str) }`? You can't just make that its own function because what if you automatically call `foo_bar` and the function foo was not in there? Then what ever you had in foo won't be global to use.

Comment: Please elaborate. ATM it sounds like a misconeception.

Comment: @VolkerK I wanted to call the function foo which was nested inside of foo_bar. In my actual codes, foo is assigned with a variable so I have to do something with the variable and then return the results. The reason why I nested many functions within foo_bar is because it would be safe to just use the other functions globally without calling for one at a time. If I nested all my functions inside a single function, it would be easier for me to just call a function I wanted any where in a different file.

Comment: Still not 100% clear but I guess I just have to wait for your next question ( and I have a feeling there will be a next question associated with this one ;-) )

Comment: But you do realize that function foo() and function bar(), once declared, are in no way, shape or form related to or associated with function foo_bar() and/or class foo? And that you will get a `Cannot redeclare foo\foo()` error when you call foo_bar() again? So far you really don't gain _any_ advantage from this approach. So why not put function foo( and function bar() directly in the namespace - where they end up being declared anyway...?

Comment: Yes, I do understand what you are saying, but I am not getting any cannot redeclare notice. I actually had to just call the namespace and then the function foo. It actually gave me the results I wanted. I am also just requiring the file once so I would assume that I would only be calling foo_bar once a page load.

Comment: But why call foo_bar() anyway if it is your _goal_ to have foo() and bar() being accessible via \foo\foo() and \foo\bar()? You require the file, the functions are in there, no mambojambo necessary. At best it's very bad design. The only thing that comes to mind* is that you want to populate different functionality via foo()/bar() depending on some condition. But there are much better ways to do that. Since you're obviously already dealing with classes, "classical" polymorphism would be one option. )* my mind, so this could be an argument by ignorance....

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @VolkerK So you're saying to stuff everything in the namespace like `namespace foo { }`? And no. I am not being ignorant. I have very little knowledge of how to properly use namespaces because I am used to using constructors in my class without namespaces. I actually would like to know more on how to properly use namespaces because the PHP docs don't explain this type of situation on it so I don't know a lot about what I should and shouldn't do.

Comment: @PaulCrovella Thanks. I will keep that in mind. I am still new to this type of forum. In the generic forums, we are allowed to post more to explain ourselves.

Comment: "stuff everything in the namespace like namespace" - that's what you're doing right now (when foo_bar() is called). I just don't see why you have to call a function to do that.

Comment: @VolkerK Then please lead me in the right direction. I just started namespaces yesterday so I have no clue what is the proper way of doing it.

Comment: This is not about namespaces. The same thing would happen without namespaces in which case foo() and bar() would just be normal ("global") functions. I still do not understand what you're trying to get out of this, so I can't point in any direction.

Comment: @VolkerK I'm just trying to use the functions globally. That's all. Function foo is actually going to be used as bbcode. So I want to use those functions in any page without actually having to manually require the file, call the class, and then the function.

Comment: Have it your way. It's wrong, but I don't care....

Comment: @VolkerK How am I wrong? You haven't even given me a single step forward. All you're doing is criticizing my theory and saying that it's "wrong" yet you won't point me in any kind of direction. People like you make the PHP community look bad because everyone thinks the PHP community have trolls who won't help. In fact, you should be asking yourself if you're the ignorant one. I obviously want help, but all you're doing is criticizing. So who is the ignorant one again?

Comment: You got your answer how it's technically possible. I invite you to study other projects and how they do it. I also like to point to the original mission goal of stackoverflow, which doesn't include personal one-to-one tutoring.

Answer (score 0):

There are no inner/nested functions/methods/classes in php (yet?).
Once foo_bar() gets executed the function foo() gets declared/defined "outside" any function/method/class, i.e. in your case as a function directly under the namespace \foo

```
<?php
namespace foo {
    class bar {
        static function foo_bar() {
            // even though function baz() only is declared once foo_bar()
            // is invoked
            function baz() {
                return('This is baz');
            }
            // the scope where it gets declared is outside
            // the function/method and class
        }
    }
    // <--- so that would be here - figuratively speaking
}

namespace lalala {
    echo 'baz() exists: ', function_exists('\foo\baz') ? 'yes':'no', "\r\n";

    \foo\bar::foo_bar(); // now \foo\baz gets declared
    echo 'baz() exists: ', function_exists('\foo\baz') ? 'yes':'no', "\r\n";
    echo \foo\baz();

    \foo\bar::foo_bar(); // will raise an error
}
```

prints

```
baz() exists: no
baz() exists: yes
This is baz
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare foo\baz() (previously declared in ...
```

It's most likely not what you want   ...or if you want it, you shouldn't ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer. Had to actually call the class then I had to call the function. Like so `\barz\foo();` assuming barz is the class.